# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 32, saw 3

Tags: python, pandas, parse-error

I am confused because my code worked perfectly before, but now I got a tokenizing error.

I just don't know how to fix that problem. It is there I need your help.

`pd.read_csv(StringIO(str1), sep=" ")` output the following error `*** pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 32, saw 3`

Be aware that `str1` is simply

`'Shares BID\n100 $312.80\n100 $312.77\n4 $312.76\n1 $312.76\n100 $312.75\n100 $312.75\n1 $312.73\n1 $312.73\n1 $312.73\n200 $312.72\n49 $312.72\n100 $312.71\n50 $312.70\n100 $312.68\n50 $312.68\n100 $312.66\n100 $312.66\n800 $312.65\n100 $312.65\n50 $312.65\n100 $312.61\n1 $312.61\n1 $312.59\n1 $312.58\n100 $312.57\n1 $312.57\n1 $312.56\n60 $312.55\n1 $312.55\n100 $312.51\nTotal Shares: 467,365'`

How can I get rid of that tokenizing error?

Comment: the last line `'Total Shares: 467,365'` parses to 3 things when parser was expecting 2.  I'd chuck that last part

Comment: `pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(str1.rsplit('\n', 1)[0]), sep=" ")`